# Why is this a valid conclusion?

Tags: logic

I have the following argument:
S1: $ (\neg (R \vee Q)) \wedge P $
S2: $ P \rightarrow Q $
S3: $ P \wedge Q $

Conclusion :
S: $R$

When I run it through a logic checker, it’s valid. The premises contradict each other, though, so I’m confused why this is the case.

Comment: +1 : good question

Comment: Vacuously true. Any triplet $(p,q,r)$ that satisfies all three $S_1, S_2, S_3$ (spoiler: there are no such triplets at all!) also satisfies $r$. (And also $\text{~}r$.) This is a way to say - if your system of axioms is inconsistent, anything can be concluded from it.

Comment: ... so to expound on Stinking Bishops comment, it is *BECAUSE* the premises contradict each other that *any* result will be valid.  And an argument is essentially a large IF (premises are true) THEN (conclusion) statement. And if the premises are false then the argument is essentially IF (FALSE) THEN (conclusion) and... well, that *is* true.

Comment: This is also called the [Principle of Explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion).

Comment: Ah I see, thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The premises of this argument are **unsatisfiable** (there exists no interpretation which makes all of the premises true).

Therefore, **any** formula is a logical consequence of these premises.

Indeed, this is the case for any set of unsatisfiable premises.

To see why this is the case, note that

$ [((\neg (R \vee Q)) \wedge P) \wedge (P \rightarrow Q) \wedge (P \wedge Q)] \rightarrow R$

is a **Tautology** as the antecedent of the implication is a **Contradiction**.

Therefore, $ R $ is a logical consequence of the premises:

$ (\neg (R \vee Q)) \wedge P, P \rightarrow Q, P \wedge Q \vDash R $